# Preferring newer results with Zend Lucene

Tags: php, symfony, zend-search-lucene

I'm using Zend Lucene in a Symfony 2 project, via EWZSearchBundle. It's all working well, but now that the site has bedded in for a few months we're finding that some of the search results for some keywords, while perfectly accurate, aren't great.

As a first step, I'd like newer articles to be prioritised over older ones. Is there a way to do this with Luence (I can't find anything relevant in the docs, though I may have missed it), or should I do this as a layer above the Lucene search (i.e., loop through the hits and add a fudge factor to the scores based on the article age)?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use a custom sort of the search hits that ranks newer results over older results if they otherwise score the same.